# Custom control causes a crash on MAUI app on Release only

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

*NB : As I was writing this question and investigating to give more precision, I actually found the solution. I'll leave the question in case it saves someone else the time I spent on this.*

I am using in my MAUI project a custom control I created myself, and I ended up in a weird situation : everything works perfectly fine in Debug, but as soon as I switch to Release, the app doesn't launch anymore, and crashes as soon as the loading screen ends.

I ended up finding a parameter binding in my custom control was the cause (commenting it makes the app launch normally), but after isolating my control in a different project, it worked without any problem, whether I'm in Debug or Release configuration.

The custom control as used in my project :

```xml
<utils:SwitchableView UseMainView="{Binding MyParameter}">
    <!--Content of the Control. Basically, two views, and we switch which one is displayed according to UseMainView.-->
</utils:SwitchableView>
```

MyParameter definition in the ViewModel :

```cs
public static bool MyParameter 
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay time to answer my own question. The solution was very simple : just don't make `MyParameter` static. It seems making the parameter static messes a bit with the compiler on Release configuration.
*(If anyone wants to comment about the WHY, feel free to do so, I'd be happy to understand the reason behind this behavior.)*

```cs
public bool MyParameter 
{
    get
    {
        return true; // Return any value you need for your parameter here.
    }
}
```